# Is it possible to manipulate shown DOM independently of innerHTML in custom elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-element

It seems to me that "custom elements" should be able to do this.

Is it possible to create completely custom elements with JS's `customElements`, such that the rendered image is completely specified by the JS (ideally in HTML), and not necessarily related to the DOM's `innerHTML`

### Example from standard HTML

To give an example from existing HTML code, the `<li>` element's DOM `innerHTML` does not represent its rendered form.

On Firefox, this is shown in the Inspector like this:

```html
<li>
  ::marker
  List item
</li>
```

### Examples

If what I want is possible, it'd be possible to create a custom `<li>`, which would behave like this:

Given the HTML

```html
<my-li>Statement</my-li>
```

Internally, the browser would then generate this:

```html
<div tag="my-li">
    <img selector="marker" src="bullet.svg"/>
    Statement
</div>
```

Then, you could access the bullet like this:

```css
my-li::marker { }
```

The inspector would thus show:

```html
<my-li>
  ::marker
  Statement
</my-li>
```

Similarly, imagine this:

```html
<duplicate-div><button>X</button></duplicate-div>
```

is internally represented by something like

```html
<div tag="duplicate-div">
    <div selector="first">
        <button>X</button>
    </div>
    <div selector="second">
        <button>X</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Motivation (please **don't** tell me how to do *this*):

I want to make a checkbox since styling the default checkbox is nigh impossible, and wanted using it to be as simple as writing

```html
<check-box>Label</check-box>
```

---

Is something like this possible?

Comment: From your question it is unclear if you have experience with the Custom Elements API. Your use of the ``tag`` **attribute** is an indication you may **_not_** grasp Custom Element basics yet. Part of the answer would probably be a 'course' on the difference between **Autonomous Elements** and **Customized Built-In Elements** (the latter Apple still refuses to implement in Safari) So indeed the answer would probable be: Read the manual first, try some code, then come back with any questions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom elements and give it a custom functionality with JavaScript. If you want a `custom-li` you can use this code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). Also **VERY IMPORTANT**, you can access the `::marker` with `list-style` which is explain [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp).

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. The meat of my problem is whether I can have the rendered page be based on internally JS-generated DOM instead of the actual `innerHTML` of the custom element.
Also, the `::marker` thing already exists. You *can* use `li::marker` in CSS. What I'm asking is to be able to support it in a custom element.

Comment: @schuelermine You can as long as when you create the custom element, you use `class custom-li extends HTMLLIElement`

Comment: I see, but I am searching for a more general solution.

Comment: @schuelermine I don't understand why I am downvoted. Also what do you mean by a more general solution?

Comment: I presume the down vote is because some StackOverflow Users consider an answer with merely links bad practice. In this case I would agree; the minimum you can do is copy/paste some code from the References you are linking to. And don't use 'here' links, just leave the URI as is, so it is clear where the link goes to. In all, your answer is *too easy* here... you might as well have said **RTFM**. I upvoted, because you are a fairly new SO user, you should have gotten an instructional comment, not a down vote.